# Fast way of checking for language in csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, nltk

I have a huge csv-file and one column has rows with summaries in different languages. My goal is to sort out those paragraphs that are not written in english.
I don't mind if some words get sorted wrong.

My current code is working but as I'm still a beginner I fear ..it's not really up to speed. Meaning it takes very long this way and as I have about 80k rows I guess I'd still be sitting here next week waiting.
I've checked for solutions but didn't find anything that worked for me, since the langdetections used seemed to be for a small amount of data.

```
import langdetect
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


test = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep='\t',header=0,index_col=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, usecols = ("TI","AB","PY","DI"),dtype = str)

stop_e = stopwords.words('english')
worte = gutenberg.words()

for line in test["AB"]:
    if type(line) == str:
        tokens = word_tokenize(line)
    for token in tokens:
        if token.isalpha()and token not in stop_e and not in worte:
```

After this I'm currently just printing stuff to check if my code is working so far.

Edit. This is faster already, since I skip rows that are purely english. But as was pointed out in the comments: I'm still deleting by word, as I don't know how to remove entire paragraphs.

```
for line in alle["AB"]:
    if type(line) == str:
        if detect(line) == 'en':
            pass
        else:
            tokens = word_tokenize(line)
            for token in tokens:
                if token.isalpha()and token not in stop_e and token not in worte: 
#del word
```

Do you have any ideas for improvement? I guess my problem is that every word is checked with the whole Gutenberg-corpus..but is there a faster way to do this?

Using `from nltk.corpus import words` as a corpus instead of Gutenberg seems to be a bit faster but not significantly.

Sample of my dataframe. The summaries in AB are all english here but I want to throw out any german/spanish/others that made it into the csv.

```
TI  AB  PY  DI
83009   Disability and inclusive education in times of...   When communities fall into decline, disabled p...   2014    10.1080/01425692.2014.919845
83010   Transforming marginalised adult learners' view...   Adult learners on Access to Higher Education c...   2014    10.1080/01425692.2014.919842
83011   Home education, school, Travellers and educati...   The difficulties Traveller pupils experience i...   2014    10.1080/01425692.2014.919840
83012   Promoting online deliberation quality: cogniti...   This research aims to contribute to the theory...   2014    10.1080/1369118X.2014.899610
83013   Living in an age of online incivility: examini...   Communication scholars have examined the poten...   2014    10.1080/1369118X.2014.899609
```

Comment: what comes after the `if token.isalpha()`? Also can you show us a sample of the dataframe? As for speed - you are doing a fair bit of loops and `if`s. Depending on the need, you can simply remove words that fall into `stop_e` and `worte` before doing your language check. This may reduce the time considerably

Comment: Currently not much. I'm using a "print(token) else: pass" to check if it's working. In the end I want to remove non-english tokens and keep the others. I'll try to edit in a sample of my df. Removing words that fall into either of those checks isn't in my interest as I want to keep those.

Comment: Some words (`the`, `and`, `it`, `of`) are more frequent/likely than others (`banana`, `deliberation`, `incivility`).  Maybe checking for those more likely words first rather than checking the whole dictionary would give you a faster way to get a quick "it's English" answer; then only those which don't contain a reasonable number of such words go on to the more complex (and time consuming) checks?  Not really my area so apologies if this comment's not useful.

Comment: You `import langdetect` but never use it. I believe it should work much better especially for strings which don't contain a good set of stop words, though all the language-detection modules I have tried have a significant confusion problem (but this can be alleviated a lot if you exclude the requirement to distinguish between closely related languages like Danish/Norwegian, Serbian/Macedonian, etc).

Comment: Words like "the, and, it" are in the stopword-corpus.But maybe skipping those alltogether could speed things up a bit. Other than that your idea of only checking words that don't pass an initial test is interesting. Not sure if I know how to do it, but I'll start looking into it.

Comment: @tripleee so simply use detect(string) to check? I don't really care about distinguishing anyway - if it's not english, it's going to be deleted. (I think I used langdetect in an earlier version of the code but it didn't work..don't remember though, so I'll try again.)

Comment: @Seeamoebe, what is the end goal here? in your question it seems like you want to remove paragraphs that are written in another language, but in the comments it seems more like removing individual words. If the latter is the case - my question is why? Due to the fact that some words can appear in more than one language and then you have a whole new list of issues to deal with at that point

Comment: @MattR I would like to remove paragraphs. But I'm not certain about a method to do that.. except checking every individual word, which is why I'm currently trying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you mentioned wanted to remove the entire paragraph. Here is how I would handle it. In your first code-snippet you `import langdetect` but do not actually use it. `langdetect.dectect()` can take an entire string. You do not need to split the words. Example:

```
langdetect.detect('using as example')
# output
'en'
```

By not splitting the entire string into single words this will cut down on the time. This is due to `detect()` not being called for *each* word. Here is a small sample of how I would tackle it:

```
import pandas as pd
import langdetect
# creating a sample dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':['es muy bueno','run, Forest! Run!','Ήξερα ότι θα εξετάζατε τον Μεταφραστή Google', 'This is Certainly en']})
# calling detect on each sentence
df1['Language'] = df1['Sentence'].apply(lambda x: langdetect.detect(x))
# filtering the entire dataset for only english
filtered_for_english = df1.loc[df1['Language'] == 'en']
# output
               Sentence Language
3  This is Certainly en       en
```

But here is the downside to using `langdetect`... it is a Port from Google's language detection from Java to Python [According to the Docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect?). Translators are not always correct:

Look at the popular phrase from the english movie *Forest Gump* passed through `langdetect.detect('run, Forest! Run!')`. this returns `ro` for Romanian. You can try removing punctuation, stop-words, [stemming and lemmatizing](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html), or simply remove problematic nouns/verbs to get a more accurate reading. These are things you will need to test yourself.