# How to drop (or deal with) rows in a csv file if cells on the row contain Hebrew, Arabic, or Russian characters?

Tags: python, csv, unicode, non-ascii-characters

For a webscraping project, I succesfully extracted information from a social media platform with BeautifulSoup and Selenium in Python.
All data has been stored in a CSV-file with--after cleaning--12.000 unique observations, and with different 13 variables (columns).

The CSV-file appears as follows:

```
id, medium, text_1, text_2, ...
1, image, ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. #LoremIpsum' ], ['In imperdiet'], ...
2, video, ['Sed nisi arcu, laoreet a pretium et, elementum sit amet augue #LoremIpsum #sitamet' ], ['onsectetur adipiscing'], ...
3, none, ['Nam ultrices lobortis ipsum in tincidunt. #ipsum #lobortis' ], ['efficitur magna '], ...
4, none, ['Hebrew Hebrew Hebrew Hebrew Hebrew Hebrew # Hebrewhahstag' ], [' Hebrew Hebrew text'], ...
5, image, ['Russian Russian Russian Russian, i.e. text in Cyrillic alphabet #Cyrillic_hahstag' ], ['Cyrillic text'], ...
6, none, ['Arabic Arabic Arabic Arabic, i.e. text in Arabic alphabet #Arabic_hahstag' ], [' Arabic text'], ...
7, image, ['Arabic Russian Hebrew English Smileys and Emojis #Emoji #English #Arabic' ], ['Cyrillic text'], ...
```

My question is twofold.

1. What Python-script can I write in order to iterate over the text1 and text2 columns and converts whatever non-Latin text is found into a Latin equivalent?

   2.What Python-script can I write that will drop every row/line in the csv file if it contains non-Latin characters.

Self-evidently, I do not want to delete the rows containing "@ mentions", or "#-tags", because that leaves me with zero rows.

So more concretely, in the example above: it would be my desire to either convert the non-Latin information of the cases 4, 5, 6, 7 into latin text, or to drop those cases completely. If possible, the first solution has of course my preference.

I have been playing around with regular expressions, with encode, with unicode and UTF, but I haven't been successful yet in writing a code that exactly does what I would like it to do. Similarly, and to the best of my knowledge, this specific issue hasn't been addressed yet on this (or other) online expert communities.

I have to confess that my Python skills are beginner level.

I would enormously appreciate your help and efforts.

Thank you very much!

Thomas

Comment: Check out the builtin `ord()` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord . `chr()` may help too: `[print(chr(i)) for i in range(255)]`

Comment: You should have a look at the [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) library, which transliterates any text to an ASCII representation. Note that it will also transliterate some letters within the Latin script, eg. "é"→"e".

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful comments. I have puzzling around without succes. But, I have been able to get a general language identification on the basis of the google translate API (as found in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543032/fast-way-of-checking-for-language-in-csv). For now that did the job for me!